# Create a plane mesh with pointcloud in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created pointcloud with all points in an exact plane. I want the pointcloud to be highlighted and shown as a rectangle shape when the mouse is rolled over. For that, I think the pointcloud has to be converted in to a mesh, first.
I've googled for hours and tried to read thee.js documentation too. But couldn't find any solution. Could you please help me convert this pointcloud to a mesh. Thank you very much

```
        <script>

        if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {
            document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );
        }
        var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45.0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 5, 3500 );
            camera.position.z = 2500;
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            createScene();
        }

        function createScene() {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
                var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                var positions = [];

                for ( var i = 0; i < 500; i ++ ) {
                    for ( var j = 0; j < 300; j ++ ) {
                    var y = j;
                    var x = i; 
                    var z = 0;
                    positions.push( x, y, z );
                    }
                }

                geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

                var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {color: 0xFFFFFF} );
                points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
                scene.add( points );
        }

        function animate( time ) {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

        </script>
```

Comment: Since you're constructing your point cloud using random positions, you'll need to first decide how you want the rectangle created. If world-aligned is good enough, then you can use the point cloud's bounding box to determine the corners of the rectangle, and create your `Mesh` accordingly. But if you want a tighter fit, you'll need to figure out how to create the bounds of the minimal area which encapsulates your points, and create your `Mesh` from that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm new to three.js so I don't understand your reply completely. I've changed the code and now the pointcloud is generated without math.random. Could you please explain it a bit more now?. Thanks very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty modification of your sample, basically it creates a thin box with the same dimensions than your pointcloud and toggle its visibility when the mouse is getting over (using a raycaster). As far as I know there is no direct/built-in way to turn a pointcloud into a plane/mesh.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Three.js - wall construction</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;">
        <script>

        if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {
            document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );
        }
        var camera, scene, renderer, controls, box, boxMaterial;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {


          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
          renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45.0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 5, 3500 );
          camera.position.z = 2500;
          controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
          createScene();
          renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false); 
        }

        function createScene() {

          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
          var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
          var positions = [];

          for ( var i = -250; i < 250; ++i) {
              for ( var j = -150; j < 150; ++j) {
                positions.push(i, j, 0);
              }
          }

          geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

          var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF});
          points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
          scene.add(points);

          //create box based on pointcloud extends  
          var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 300, 1 );
          boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000FF});
          boxMaterial.visible = false //set invisible by default
          box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, boxMaterial);
          scene.add(box);
        }

        function onMouseMove (e) {

          var pointer = {
            x: (e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
            y: - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1
          }  

          var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
          raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera)

          var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([box])

          boxMaterial.visible = !!intersects.length
        }

        function animate(time) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          controls.update();
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes,this is right! Thanks so much for helping me out. :)